# Randomize/Shuffle HTTP requests made to Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have the following situation: a very expensive data calculation task, which is performed for every http request made against a REST resource.

Let's say a customer sends 1000 requests. Nginx then takes up to 2 days to respond to all of the requests.

We're fine with that.

But that should block the endpoint for all other customers.

I'm looking for a way to cheat the "first come first serve" way that Nginx deals with incoming requests, so other customers will be served during the period.

I've tried Google but so far no luck.

I thank you in advance if you can suggest anything that could solve my issue.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Then what you need is: per client rate limiting. Don't allow any client to issue more requests than you can handle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is not the case. We won't limit the number of requests per client.